# Changing a Fiber Internet Modem?

Tags: ethernet, modem, fiber

For Example, if for some Reasons, I must change a Fiber Internet Modem.

Would be a Media Converter (Fiber to Ethernet) and an Ethernet Router, a good Choice to set up a basic Internet Connection ?

Is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006ML8DCI) Model the right Device to convert Fiber to Ethernet ?

How to know if it is Fiber to Ethernet or Ethernet to Fiber ?

Comment: Is your fiber "modem" from you ISP? If so, you likely can't just replace it with a media converter, ISP's use a very different set of standards for fiber distribution vs Ethernet. Can you provide the details (make and model) the ONT or "modem" you have now? An Optical Network Terminal is much more than just a "modem" or media converter. BTW, I put "modem" in quotes because it is a true misnomer in this context, it is NOT a modem.

Comment: You cannot use a fiber media converter for this... This ONT is essentially a media AND protocol converter, converting fiber to copper and xDSL to Ethernet. Using a standard media converter will not yield any result at all (or just an error). If you must change the fiber ONT, you would need another compatible unit, and probably one with it's optical or interface MAC registered with your ISP for it to work.

Comment: Correct... I will add it as an answer.

Comment: It simply means the Siligense unit is performing multiple roles, it is converting the media (optical to copper) and the protocol (xDSL to Ethernet) in a single unit.

Comment: I found some called "Fiber-Gateways" or "FTTH-Router" , but it's probably as you said, it must be approved by the ISP. Perhaps it was a Mistake to call it ADSL or xDSL because it is related to Cooper Lines and is specificate for Cooper Lines. And maybe because Fiber use Light Waves/Photons therefor have other units as measure(different Electro magnetic characteristics) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP is using a Siligense SAS SGA441SW ONT, or Optical Network Terminal, to convert optical xDSL to Ethernet. It is performing both a media conversion (optical to copper) AND a protocol conversion of xDSL (which the standards can vary) to Ethernet (IEEE 802.3).

A media converter as you linked in your original question will either not function at all, or will just produce an error as it is only doing half of the necessary requirement for connectivity, attempting to convert Optical Ethernet (which this is not) to Copper Ethernet, and making no provisions for the xDSL connectivity.

These types of ONT devices are often only available from you ISP, or if you purchase them outside of your ISP they many need to be approved by them. Regardless, the optical or interface MAC address likely would need to be provisioned by your ISP prior to it being a functional replacement unit.